# Object Expected IE8 JS/JQuery issue IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

This is my first post on here though I browse through SO a lot for answers.  I'm running into a problem where IE8 will keep throwing "Object Expected" error.  I used IE8's Developer tools and it points to "mymh.js" file

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/MyMHome/javascript/mymh.js"></script>
```

mymh.js file only has the following code

```
    $(document).ready(function() {          

        $('#hNumber').focus();

        $('#ddlDir').change(function () {

            var selVal = $('#ddlDir').val();

             if (selVal == 'N' || selVal == 'S' || selVal == 'E' || selVal == 'W'){

             $.getJSON('/MyMHome/DimeServlet?strDir='+$('#ddlDir option:selected').val(), function(data) {

                    $('#ddlSt')
                    .find('option')
                    .remove()
                    .end()

                $.each(data, function(i,field){
                    var name = field;
                    $('#ddlSt')

                    .append('<option value= ' + '"' + name + '"' + '>' + name + '</option>');   
                    });
                });

                $('#ddlSt').focus();    
             }else{ 

                    $('#ddlSt')
                    .find('option')
                    .remove()
                    .end()
                    .append('<OPTION selected value="">Choose a direction first</OPTION>');

                }                   
        })
        .trigger('change');             

        $('#reset').click(function(){
             $('#ddlSt')
            .find('option')
            .remove()
            .end()
            .append('<OPTION selected value="">Choose a direction first</OPTION>'); 
             $('#hNumber').focus();                
        });

        $('#hNumber').bind('keyup', function() {
            if($('#hNumber').val().length == 5){
                    $('#ddlDir').focus();
            }
        });             

        $('#submitQuery').click(function(){
            var houseNumber = $('#hNumber').val();
            if(houseNumber.replace(/\s+/g, '').length == 0){
                alert('Please enter a house number.');
                $('#hNumber').focus();  
                return false;
            }else if( (!$.isNumeric(houseNumber)) || houseNumber.indexOf('-') > -1 || houseNumber.indexOf('.') > -1){
                alert('Please enter numbers only. You will be prompted later, if the address requires a suffix.');
                $('#hNumber').focus();  
                return false;
            }else if(houseNumber < 100 || houseNumber > 12999){
                alert('Please enter a house number between 100 and 12999');
                $('#hNumber').focus();
                return false;
            }else if($('#ddlDir option:selected').val() == 'none'){
                alert('Please select a street direction.');
                $('#ddlDir').focus();
                return false;
            }       
        });         

        $('form').keypress(function(e) {
              if (e.keyCode == '13') {
                 e.preventDefault();
                 if($('#ddlSt').is(":focus")){
                     $('#submitQuery').trigger('click');
                 }
                 else{
                     return false;
                 }
               }
        });
});
```

The error points to the `<script ...  mymh.js></script>` but in the debugger it points to `$document.ready(function() {`

Anyone see anything wrong as to why IE8 would keep throwing that error?

Comment: You're not loading any other JS libraries (like prototype) as well, right? Also, you should try using the 'Start Debugging' button in F12; the page will reload and the JS debugger will stop on the line that throws the exception, might make it easier to find the problem.

Comment: The only JS library I'm loading is the JQuery library.  And the only external JS file I'm importing is the mymh.js file.  I'll try the debugger to see what happens

Comment: Object expected line 1 in mymh.js. which is  $(document).ready(function() {

Comment: if you put an alert prior to document.ready like this alert($), does it return [Object object] or undefined?

Comment: Try `$(document.documentElement).ready(function(){`

Comment: Have you tried replacing that first `$` with `jQuery`? i.e. `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { /* code */ });`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try placing a semicolon at the end of line 16

from

```
$('#ddlSt')
.find('option')
.remove()
.end()

$.each(data, function(i,field){
```

to

```
$('#ddlSt')
.find('option')
.remove()
.end();

$.each(data, function(i,field){
```

Comment: OMG.  How did I miss that.  That fixed it for me.  Grr IE8 is such a headache.  It worked for all the other browsers

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function() { });
```

This statement may throw Object Expected error because of following reasons:

First, If our link to external javascript file (Eg. jquery-1.8.2.min.js) is not correct. Make sure that your link is at the right path. I have kept my file inside "js" folder and gave the path  as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
```

Second, If we write script tag as:

```
<script type="application/javascript"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem when using jQuery 2.0.0 in IE8. According to the jQuery site "jQuery 2.x does not support Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8". Replacing jQuery 2.0.0 with jQuery 1.10.2 fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

Bit of a old post but it maybe comes in handy for people passing by, I had the same problem, i removed the defer attribute in the script tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer" src="js/libs/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
```

into:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

This may not be relevant, but I just solved the same kind of issue with IE8 - code that ran fine on IE9 and everything else choked on IE8.

The answer was as simple as changing

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/myjavascript.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myjavascript.js"></script>
```

... in other words, JQuery first. This fixed the problem for me; YMMV.