# Message: Object expected error in IE8

Tags: javascript

I'm getting the object expected error in IE8. It's working good in chrome & FF.

Actually, error occurred on a javascript method.

for your reference,

```
function checkForm(idNum, varNum) { alert(234); }

//calling function here. 
checkForm(idNum, varNum);
```

getting error in this line.

i have called this method in document.ready & select box onchange events.

Thanks.

Comment: can you share the contents of the method

Comment: need more brief and code

Comment: Since we don't know what `checkForm`, `idNum` or `varNum` are, there is very little we can do. However, have a look at the related questions on the right hand side of this page, maybe you find something helpful.

Comment: thanks. i have commented the content of the method. but still i'm getting the same error.

Comment: write the function content

Comment: check if your script tag has attribute type="text/javascript"

Comment: Thanks. checkForm(idNum, varNum) { alert(234); }. Method has this code alone..

Comment: yes, karaxuna. I have checked the attribute type. it is type="text/javascript"

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524243/object-expected-ie8-js-jquery-issue-ie8

Comment: Is the function actually defined as `checkForm(idNum, varNum) { alert(234); }` or as `function checkForm(idNum, varNum) { alert(234); }`

Comment: Thanks smartlemon. i have used function keyword in my method..

Comment: thanks oleg. i've checked. but everything is fine..still error over there..

Comment: Can't you just post more code?..

Comment: Object expected.... calling a function that doesn't return? I think that might do it.... returning undefined? As in no object.... from what I have gathered at least....

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using jQuery if you are using `document.ready`? As in `$(document).ready()`

If you are then you want to give `ready` a function, not call a function

As in instead of having

```
$(document).ready(checkForm(idNum, varNum));
```

you would use

```
$(document).ready(function(){checkForm(idNum, varNum);});
```

`ready` is just a function and is expecting an object to be passed to it, just like `checkForm` a function is an object, just like a number or string, and can be passed to other functions and then called, like so...

```
function foo(bar){
    bar();
}

function foobar(){
    console.log("foobar has been called");
}

foobar();
foo(foobar);
```

The output of this being

```
"foobar has been called"
"foobar has been called"
```

If I understand what you are doing by the comments...